# WPF TextBox displayed value is not equal to TextBox.Text

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, textbox

I check the postal code for about 60 countries. The user enters a postal code which is checked against the rules for that country. The US is an exception where I can auto-fill the value based on other street address information already entered. In some ways it's basically an auto-correction feature. The problem is the auto-filled value never re-displays if it matches the previous .Text value - the 'erroneous' zip code just entered by the user remains displayed!

For example, field contains "12345", user deletes the "5", my property setter puts the value back to "12345", the binding getter returns "12345" (and at this point my _TextChanged event fires) but WPF still displays the user edited text "1234"!

How do I force WPF to redisplay the value?

To simplify the example I have hard-coded the ZipCode value (in the app it is computed in a separate method):

```
public String ZipCode
{
    get { return _address.ZipCode; }
    set
    {
        _address.ZipCode = "12345";
        RaisePropertyChanged("ZipCode");
    }
}
```

Here is the XAML:

```
<TextBox Name="ZipBox" 
         Text="{Binding Path=ZipCode, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
         TextChanged="ZipBox_TextChanged" />
```

WPF knows the field changed cause it always fires this event. But none of those methods force WPF to correctly display "12345".

```
private void ZipBox_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    ZipBox.InvalidateVisual();
    ZipBox.InvalidateMeasure();
    ZipBox.UpdateLayout();
}
```

Edit: I also have created a custom static extension method .Refresh(this UIElement uiElement) which calls UIElement.Dispatcher.Invoke() and that also does not force the redraw.

Comment: What is ZipBox?  And where is the ZipCode property?  Don't you need to actually change the ZipCode property?  Shouldn't you do this in the TextChanged event? What updates the ZipCode property?

Answer (score 2):

Min Zhu on the Microsoft forum came up with a solution. Here is the code:

```
bool flagTextChanged = true;
private void TextBox_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
  TextBox txt = sender as TextBox;
  if (flagTextChanged && txt != null)
  {
    flagTextChanged = false;
    Binding b = BindingOperations.GetBinding(txt, TextBox.TextProperty);
    if (b != null)
    {
      txt.ClearValue(TextBox.TextProperty);
      BindingOperations.SetBinding(txt, TextBox.TextProperty, b);
    }
    flagTextChanged = true;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean this occurs after the user edits the text manually and then leaves the box?  If so, the issue may be that the binding system doesn't want to override what the user is typing and there is an implicit assumption that the value being set by the text box Text will match the value if you call get on the property, since no exceptions are being thrown during the set.  This is one of the down-sides to 'magic properties' where the set value is mutated rather than validated, as there are many consumers of properties that assume the following is true if the setter doesn't throw an exception:

```
Instance.X = value;
Debug.Assert(Instance.X == value);
```

One idea that avoids this problem would be to set a flag that prohibits editing of the ZipCode field if it has been automatically determined (by binding IsReadOnly, perhaps.)

Comment: Actually, the user never leaves the field as the XAML setting UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged forces each typed character to be sent to my validation routine (within the setter). This really seems like a flaw in WPF: I expect the value of the .Text property to match the value displayed.

Comment: @user610342 - The default WPF controls tend to lean towards a more passive validation, using ValidationRules on the bindings or throwing exceptions from the bound properties. Sounds like you are doing a more active validation, by preventing/manipulating the user input from your data object.

Comment: @user610342, If the text can mutate while the user is typing (due to the setter changing the value), this creates complex boundary conditions for the TextBox control, as it has no idea of the correct location for the data entry caret if the value can arbitrarily change.  You're essentially violating the expected usage contract for how a TextBox expects its Text property to behave, which creates the odd symptoms you're observing.

Comment: WPF handles cases where the setter changes the value entered programmatically quite eloquently. Note the key word here is 'changes'. So, if I change my setter to _address.ZipCode += "#" then WPF always throws away the user input and redisplays the programmtically set Zipcode (with trailing "#"s). And it places the caret within this new string right after the position where the user entered their character (which of-course is not displayed). So, its not a mutation violation but rather WPF has simply cached a display value it 'thinks' does not require updating.

Answer (score 0):

I believe if you put a custom IValueConverter that does nothing but return the passed value, then the TextBox will update correctly.

Otherwise, you should be able to do:

```
ZipBox.GetBindingExpression(TextBox.TextProperty).UpdateTarget();
```

Comment: I previously tried GetBindingExpression().UpdateTarget(). That does not do the trick. WPF already has the correct binding so getting it again only replaced ZipBox.Text value of "12345" with "12345" yet it continues to display "1234". I will try IValueConverter.....

Comment: Using IValueConverter did not work - field still displays user value, not programmatic value.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question, but it's never been properly answered, so here's my suggestion.
You need to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

Depending if it's a ViewModel or code-behind of a Window (this is a Window example):

```
public class MyWindow: Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
   ...
}
```

Then implement a version of INotifyPropertyChanged within that class (there are many out there, but this is the one I use):

```
public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;


private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName = "")
{
    if (PropertyChanged != null)
    {
        PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}

private bool SetField<T>(ref T field, T value, string propertyName)
{
    if (EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(field, value))
    {
        return false;
    }

    field = value;
    OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
    return true;
}
```

And then simply use it with a property:

```
private string _text;
public string Text
{
    get { return _text; }
    set { SetField(ref _text, value, "Text"); }
}
```

Answer (score -3):

I'm not particularly familiar with WPF but I do a lot of web programming.  You could try firing a post to reload the entire page (or just the textbox with ajax) and that should allow you to set the new value.

Comment: WPF is not a web technology, so this doesn't apply in any way.

Comment: Converting your suggestion to WPF, I went up the visual tree and did .InValidateVisual on several of the Zip code Textbox parents. None of that forced WPF to redraw the page. I have never gotten .InValidateVisual to work, I seriously wonder if it does anything!